# HTML5 volume control IOS 6

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios6, html5-audio

I've been developing HTML 5 applications for a long time. I know that IOS doesn't allow the webkit to control volume of the device. So it is useless to have volume slider for IPADs for this reason. But somewhere I read that IOS 6 allows the webkit to control the volume. Is it true and if it is true, then how can I do that?

Comment: You can just use the volume control of the HTML5 audio. You have different volume controls. 1. device and 2. for the audio element.

Comment: So you mean I can simply use the audioObj.volume and it will work in IOS 6.

Comment: Yep. It would be really strange if that doesn't work. Then again: I'm not an IOS developer.